Problem while compiling git repo
I'm trying to compile a git repository of a bioinformatics package (https://github.com/MBoemo/DNAscent) and I have been running into some problems and was hoping somebody could help with this. I'm running ubuntu 22.04.
I have followed their instructions from compiling, however when I use the 'make' command in terminal it executes fine but it eventually starts spitting out a load of errors such as
../src/H5private.h:1539:14: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘__func__’ predefined identifier [-Wpedantic]

They're all basically the same error and make reference to ISO C90 does not support... My take from this was that 'make' is using the c90 compiler, despite 'CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c99 -O2' being present in their makefile document.
I tried to force use of c99 by instead trying to compilation using 'make CC=c99' which seems to fix the initial errors, but the compilation now terminates with the following:
c99 called with non ISO C99 option -ansi
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1222: H5.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/DNAscent/hdf5-1.8.14/src'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:850: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/DNAscent/hdf5-1.8.14/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:586: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/DNAscent/hdf5-1.8.14'
make: *** [Makefile:51: hdf5-1.8.14/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.a] Error 2

I'm not super experienced with this, and I'm not really sure where to go from here. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

"spitting out a load of errors" ... those actually like warnings only - does the build complete if you simply ignore them?

The readme says there should be an executable that appears in the ./bin directory, which does not. So it seems like it doesn't

Well it works for me (bin/DNAscent --version runs and shows Version: 4.0.1) - you may need to install additional libraries (I needed to add libbz2-dev for example). Check the make output for error messages.
